# Does location service in angular 2 need to be injected?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm looking at the tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5).

(scroll to the very bottom where it says "HeroDetailComponent", and select the tab hero-detail.component.ts)

All it does in order to use the location service is to import location from @angular/common, put it in the constructor parameters, and that's it. It didn't put it in the providers array, not in the module's providers array either. Is it the case that some services just get injected automatically without specifying it in the providers array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the tutorial is using the RouterModule. The RouterModule provides the `Location` and `LocationStrategy` services for you so you do not need to provide them in your AppModule. [src code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.1/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L145-L168)

```
// Router Module providers array
providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, // Location service is provided in this array
    {
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useFactory: provideLocationStrategy,
        deps: [
            PlatformLocation, [new Inject(APP_BASE_HREF), new Optional()], ROUTER_CONFIGURATION
        ]
    },
    ...
],
```

If you weren't using the RouterModule, then you would have to provide them yourself. Something like

```
// app.module.ts
providers: [
    Location, 
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
]
```

Comment: So while the RouterModule is injected to the App module, the RouterModule secretly injects its own stuff to the App module, so on the surface you're injecting one thing, but actually, it's injecting several things?

Comment: @Andy more or less. The RouterModule is simply an angular module. So it can inject it's own providers as needed. You can dig around the angular source code and see alot of the built in modules inject some providers. For example, the HttpClientModule injects HttpClient so you don't have to.